# Local cloud system

Tags: sync, cloud

as the Ubuntu One Service will be finished soon, I'm searching for alternatives. I got aware that I don't really need to give my files to an internet service like Dropbox. So I want to setup a local cloud system to sync some files between the computers in my little office. Maybe in the future I will want to sync to my own webspace via ftp.
I have tried out Unison, but as I see, it wont do the work automatically and silently in the background every 5 minutes.
Is there an application to setup a local cloud system like Ubuntu One?

Greetings

Comment: I am not sure how to do it automatically but I am sure someone elese can help you with a program to do that but an ubuntu sever system sounds like something you would need. EDIT: I did find this article that might help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/automated-provisioning-of-digitalocean-cloud-servers-with-salt-cloud-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 1):

I have used CrashPlan for quite awhile. If you just want to create a private local cloud, it cant be beat! If thats is your plan, it is totally free and unlimited.

But crashplan also provides a service like dropbox for a very affordable fee. I use both so that I have double protection.

There is also OwnCloud, but as far as I understand (I may be wrong) you have to have a web server for it. Keep in mind, some hosting plans do not allow this type of software.